# How to remove any string from a file via shell scripts?

Tags: linux, shell-script, bash-script

I try to remove string from `.bash_profile`. String is added when my shell script run:

My string at bash_profile as follows:

```
# for Myapllication
export MYAPP_HOME=/opt/myapp
```

I want to remove the strings from `.bash_profile` when myapp is removed via `rpm`.

How to remove any string from a file via shell script? (or possible alternative method)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can remove a string from a text file with `sed` (other tools exist).

For example:

```
sed -i -e '/myapp/d' .bash_profile
```

removes from `.bash_profile` every line containing the string `myapp`.

Answer (score 10):

A file like `~/.bash_profile` lives in a home directory of a user. Such a file is completely under control of the user. Global acting commands like `rpm` are not supposed to change such files.

- You usually have a base configuration file, which is delivered by the rpm package.
- You then have a global configuration file which can be used by root to overwrite some preferences specific to the given system.
- Then you have personal configuration files in your home directory which you can use to override the global setting with your personal preferences.

A command like `rpm` should only change the first one and never change the latter.

Comment: Can you suggest a URL to examine for this topic?

Comment: @Gyhot http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/77518/how-to-remove-any-string-from-a-file-via-shell-scripts/77522#77522 is a good one. If your target distribution has a `/etc/profile.d` directory, drop a file containing that `export` line there. Otherwise, you may edit `/etc/profile`, but be very careful not to wreck customizations by the system administrator.

Answer (score 3):

```
sed -i '/^export MYAPP_HOME=\/opt\/myapp$/d' ~/.bash_profile
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the vim-way:

```
ex -s +"g/MYAPP_HOME/d" -cwq file.txt
```